# Switch tab in CodeSandbox, shortcut key / hotkey

Tags: javascript, codesandbox

I was using CodeSandbox to test JavaScript codes in my browser fast. And tried hard to get the key to switch tabs, but I couldn't. I tried <kbd>Ctrl+Tab</kbd> But it would rather switch the browser tabs.

So what is the hotkey to switch tabs? if there is no direct key, what is the workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## It actually works with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

You would only have to make the page `Fullscreen` in the browser, using <kbd>F11</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

By default you can switch between tabs on Mac using option + command + left or right arrows or on PC using windows key + alt + left or right arrows.

Another option is to use control + number (1, 2, etc) to pick the tab in the corresponding order.

Your browser may have a keyboard shortcut associated with those combos. In my case I can do any of the commands in Safari, but Firefox switches browser tabs with the first combo I shared, so I just use the second option to pick individual tabs.

You can change your keyboard shortcuts by clicking the hamburger menu in the top left, going to file -> preferences -> keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: any of those doesn't work on code sandbox. have you tried it?

Comment: depends on the browser, but yes, they all work as long as my browser does not already use those shortcuts. what browser are you using? can you go to your keyboard shortcut preferences in codesandbox and review/change the shortcuts?

Comment: ctrl+1 and 2 works, thanks